# Utility icon not showing

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, icon

I am using below line of code to show the icon but instead it is showing as a dot. Tried on chrome and edge.

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:warning" alternativeText="Warning!" title="Warning" />
```

[image]

Referring this documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:icon/example

Comment: Is it a LWC? If so it should be `<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:warning" alternative-text="Warning!" title="Warning" ></lightning-icon>`.

Comment: doing it in aura. actions icons are showing up but utility icons are not showing up

Comment: Please provide more details. It might be some styling issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup within which you are showing the icon has had a (max) height set for it (or similar - could be positioning of the elements around it too); by enlarging the image you can see that you are seeing a slice through, about half way up the icon:

[image: Your snippet of icon with my hand-drawn extras]

You need to examine the markup around where you insert your image and check what CSS is being applied.